# how to update a label caption in powerpoint from excel in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I need to update a label caption using Powerpoint object from excel macro. I cant able to update.

```
Dim objPpt As PowerPoint.Application
Dim objPre As Presentation
Dim objSlide As Slide
Dim objLayout As CustomLayout
Dim objTxtBox As Shape

Set objPpt = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
Set objPre = objPpt.Presentations.Open("H:\Macro\SamplePpt.pptm")
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).lblHi.Caption = "Hello"
Set objSlide = objPre.Slides.Item(1)
Set objTxtBox = objSlide.Shapes.Item(1)

lblHi.Caption = "Hello"
```

Help me to do this....!!!!

Comment: How about `lblHi.Caption = "Hello2"` ?

Comment: no. I cant able to get this id ( lblHi ). I just add to check